# How to support private dependency management in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have built a project as a JAR+.SO with the intent that it can be shared in multiple projects and worked on in parallel. Now, however, I am not sure what the Android Studio way of supporting private dependency management is.

For reference, the project I am building is in Git and is actually an Eclipse project that produces the JAR+.SO.

What is the Android Studio way to manage these dependencies? Do I need to setup a private maven repo and reference them via Maven?

Comment: Since a Maven repo is just a directory, and the Maven plugin for Gradle makes it easy to "upload" artifacts to a local Maven repo, I'd go that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Commonsware suggested, its easy enough to use the Local Maven repository. In my case, I had to build the dependency in Eclipse, so installing the dependency involved first converting my project to a Maven project. This is done in Eclipse by Configure -> Convert to Maven project.

Once this is done, you can simply do the following:

```
mvn install
```

This will then install your artifact in the local repository. Then, in my Gradle I just updated my dependencies to pull my arfifact.

```
compile 'groupId:artifactId:1.0@aar'
```

I have not tried installing artifacts from Gradle, but I believe it is easier than my approach with Eclipse.